# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}$

Tags: limits, solution-verification

> Evaluate
> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{n}{n^2+1^2}+\dfrac{n}{n^2+2^2}+\dfrac{n}{n^2+3^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{n}{n^2+n^2}\right) $$

**My Solution:** Let $S$ denote the limit. Now observe

\begin{gather*}
\frac{n}{n^2+n^2} < \frac{n}{n^2+1} \leq \frac{n}{n^2+1} \tag{1} \\
\frac{n}{n^2+n^2} < \frac{n}{n^2+2^2} < \frac{n}{n^2+1} \tag{2} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{n}{n^2+n^2} \leq \frac{n}{n^2+n^2} < \frac{n}{n^2+1} \tag{$n$}
\end{gather*}

Now add all the equations and take the limit as $n\to\infty$. We obtain

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n^2+n^2} < S < \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^2}{n^2+1} $$

Hence

$$ \frac{1}{2} < S < 1 . $$

**Question:** Is my approach correct?

(I know that using Riemann Sum leads to the answer $S = \frac{\pi}{4}$.)

Also, can we solve it using [Sandwich Theorem of Limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)?

Comment: Your approach does not find the limit and thus is wrong

Comment: All you can conclude from your argument is that, if $S$ exists (i.e., the limit defining $S$ converges), then it satisfies $\frac{1}{2} \leq S \leq 1$.

Comment: Your approach gives a true statement, but is not going to be able to get the value of the limit you want.

Comment: You say you "know" the limit is $\frac\pi4,$ and mention Riemann integrals, but you don't say **how** you know these things.

Comment: does this answer your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386515/series-calculation-using-a-riemann-sum-and-ftc-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sum?noredirect=1